# How to limit showing the preloader once per session?

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my website I have got a preloader on each page.

```
<div id="preloader" >
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="statustext">some text</div>
</div>
```

It is triggered by this jquery:

```
//<![CDATA[
var sCookie = Cookies.get('cargado');

if (sCookie != null) 
{

    $('#preloader').hide();
}
else 
{
    $(window).on('load', function () 
    { // makes sure the whole site is loaded 
        $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation 
        $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website. 
        $('body').delay(350).css({ 'overflow': 'visible' });
        Cookies.set('cargado', 'si');

    })
}
    //]]>
```

My need is that the preloader should be shown only once for session. In other words if a user visits 10 pages on my website he should see it only once, the 1st page, no matter if he enters the website from the home page or an internal page.I came up with the solution shown above but despite setting up the cookie correctly it does not hide the preloader div.

I created a test page here: http://www.mejoresdatos.cl/testpage.html

Comment: try wrapping your if/else statement inside '$(window).on...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use localStorage/sessionStorage instead of cookies

```
 <style>
#preloader 
  {
    display:none;
  }
</style>

$(window).on('load', function () 
        { // makes sure the whole site is loaded 
            if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.                
                if(localStorage.isFirstLoadComplete==="false"){
                    $('#preloader').show(0);
                    $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation 
                    $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website. 
                    $('body').delay(350).css({ 'overflow': 'visible' });
                    localStorage.setItem("isFirstLoadComplete", "true");
                }
            } else {
                // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
            }
        });
```